# How to send notifications about failing compliance in Rudder?

Tags: rudder, notification

Think the title says it all but I want to send an email to someone when the compliance for a node isn't 100%.

I can't seem to find anywhere to do this in the portal is there a another way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in facility to send mail within Rudder; most common method is to use a monitoring software to watch compliance, and send mail if you have non-compliant message.
Some examples can be found in the [documentation](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc/_monitoring.html#_monitor_compliance) for watching file /var/log/rudder/compliance/non-compliant-reports.log which contains all non-compliant report

You can also query the API to get [compliance](http://www.rudder-project.org/rudder-api-doc/#api-Compliance-getNodeCompliance) for a specific node; with minimum scripting (or probably your existing tools can trigger action based on API answer) you can send an email.

Edit: we improved documentation on how to get notification, with a [Logstash](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc/_monitoring.html#_monitor_events) configuration example, and a [Slack](https://www.rudder-project.org/doc/compliance-and-drift-assessment.html#_overview_in_rudder) connector

Hope it helps !